# Force close TCP connection stuck in CLOSE-WAIT state

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, video-streaming

My application is requesting an m3u8 (HLS) video stream through an external plugin over the localhost (e.g 192.168.0.108:port/foobar.ts). On this localhost I have a `HttpListener` listening that catches this file request, validates it. And sends a download command for this file to the server. while the file is downloading it gets streamed back to the plugin using the `HttpListenerContext.Response.OutputStream()`. if the internet connection is fast enough it will also pre-download the upcoming fragments if available.

This works fine as long as the entire .ts fragment gets downloaded. However when the user decides to switch videos while it is in the middle of sending the data over the `HttpListenerContext.Response.OutputStream()` it causes a socket exception `System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: The socket has been shut down. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: The socket has been shut down`.

Whenever this happens a "ghost" connection seems to stay open in the background that is in the `CLOSE-WAIT` state. that has 1 byte in the rx_queue according to `/proc/net/tcp` [image]
This connection does not time out as long as the application is alive, and I seem unable to close it unless I kill the entire HttpListener.

Simply disposing of the InputStream and OutputStream, and setting the context to `null` does not close the connection either

```cs
currentContext.Response.OutputStream.Dispose();
currentContext.Request.InputStream.Dispose();
currentContext = null;
```

Is there a way to forcefully close this connection?

Comment: I've seen this a lot.  Usually refereed to a connection half open/ half closed.  I will look for solution.

Comment: Did you try wrapping the Listener with a USING statement so it would get disposed when an exception occurs?

Comment: @jdweng unfortunately I can't just wrap it in a `using`, The method in which the `outputstream` is written to doesn't necessarily have all the data in one go, so putting it in a `using` could close it too early.

Comment: Then use a semaphore like WaitOne to signal when complete so you do not exit early.

Comment: Hmm I will try that, thanks!